# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, .net-assembly

I'm having a problem using Excel in my WinForm application.
When I try it on several computers it works just fine on them, but when I try it on another computer it gives me the 'System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly' error.

I've added a reference in my project ('Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel') and even set 'Copy Local' to true.

I don't know why this is happening because all computers use the same office version(Office 2007 = Version 12).

Anyone has an idea?

thanks,
Udi

Comment: You better include those DLL files along with your own executable file - even with Office 2007 installed it doesn't mean those interop assemblies will be available. It probably work on computer having Visual Studio installed, right?

Comment: I've included it with the exe files. The files I'm using are from the "\bin\Release" directory of my project.

Comment: Installing in the wrong version of c:\program files on a 64-bit machine could explain this.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to see where it is looking for the file.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the reference in the .csproj file to make sure that the DLL is being referenced from the bin folder rather than from somewhere else.

Comment: the DLL was originally refferd from "C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\office12...\", and It doesn't exist on that computer. So I tried to load it from a network folder, which that computer had access too, Didn't work either. So' I've tried to reffer it from the local hd (created exact same folder on that computer with the dll), didn't work as well.
I didn't publish the project, just built a 'release' build. Maybe I need to write something into config.app? I don't know

Comment: Ok, in your project create a new folder and call it Assemblies (or something like that).  Stick your dependent DLLs in there, delete the reference (you might need to remove it manually from the csproj to be sure) then re-reference it from the new folder.  Right click the Assemblies folder and make sure it copies this folder to the output location.  I hope that might work for you :)

Comment: Hi, I don't see any option on the right click menu to include the "Assemblies" folder to be on the output location. Also, If my project files are on folder "x" and I will want the program to be on folder "y", will it re-refrence it to that folder by itself?

Comment: I'd imagine on the computers where it currently works, the DLL has been registered in the GAC and is being referenced from there.  By making a new folder, copying the required DLLs in there and referencing them that way you break the connection to the GAC and in theory those DLLs will automatically be copied to the output folder.  To be doubly-sure you could right click the DLLs in the assemblies folder you created (sorry not the folder itself, my bad!) and choose 'copy to output folder'.  Good luck :)

Comment: Do i need to put the "assemblies" folder as a sub folder of "\bin\release" or as a folder by itself outside of "\bin"?

Comment: Folder by itself should do the trick, somewhere in the file system amongst your solution files.  Stick the DLLs in there, delete the references in Visual Studio and then re-add them from the new folder.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. let's say my projects file are on "c:\VS2010\Project1\bin...." so when I add the reference the path it shows is from that direcory. When I put the build on tht computer I'm putting it on "c:\myProject" so it won't work because the refrence is trying to get to a folder which doesn't exist on that computer...  Maybe there's something wrong on that computer?

Comment: Are those dependent DLLs also appearing in the output folder?

Comment: Yes. It drives me crazy... Could it be a faulty OS/Office installation?

Comment: just 1 project. 8 forms and 3 classes

Comment: Ok, just to double check, could you open your project's .csproj file (say, in Notepad++ or something) and do a find for 'Interop.Excel' - just to confirm there are no erroneous references knocking about in there?  If you've already done this, my apologies.

Comment: Hi, I don't how it happened, but now it works though I did nothing new with the code and it works now. The CIO tried to re-register the dll on the rogue computer and I guess that that did the job. I guess I was right that there was something wrong with the computer. Thanks for your help and support! I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, glad it's sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Path statement on the computer that fails to load the assembly, I will bet that it is different than on the other computers.

This error is telling you that the DLL is not in the path.

For details on how Windows searches for DLLs see: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The PATH environment variable is not used to locate assemblies.

Comment: Hans: See the Microsoft article listed in my answer. It specifically lists "The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable"

Comment: That only applies to native DLLs.  Like [DllImport].