# Read single excel cell (A3) using C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to read single excel cell (A3) using C# , but this code is failing due below mentioned error . I am using SSIS script task. Please help me !!! Thanks

```
/*
   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
   Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
   The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.
*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; //use the reference in your code

namespace ST_72bc640805c54a799cae807cc596a894.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        /*
        The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
        To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
        and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.

        To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value;
        To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, null);
        To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, true);

        To use the connections collection use something like the following:
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

        Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.

        To open Help, press F1.
    */
        public void Main()
        {
            object _row = 3;
            object _column = 1;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            excelApp.Visible = false;
            excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\ETL Process\\Sample.xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
            string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.UsedRange;
            string sValue = (range.Cells[_row, _column] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(sValue); 
            //sValue has your value
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is Error**

> Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'    at
>   ST_72bc640805c54a799cae807cc596a894.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

I even added this to system 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Do you have MS Office installed on that machine? The referenced error indicates that it cannot find the DLL associated to Excel.

Comment: No i don't , its different server

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using the assembly `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Your local machine has this available as you have MS Office installed.

You have now deployed your code to a server. This server does not have Office installed. The aforementioned assembly is not part of the core .NET runtime. When your package attempts to run, it throws `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'` because you have not provided the resource that it requires.

If you chose to install Office on the server, realize that there is a licensing cost to this approach as well as an increase in the number of patches for which this server is eligible. This can lead to longer downtime/outages which might be of concern depending on your SLA.

If you think "it's just a DLL or two, I can copy them over from my machine to the server" even *if* you manage to get them all copied over and have things running, you've effectively installed Office and the above licensing will apply should you get audited.

Otherwise, your only other recourse is to recode your package to not use the assembly.

- [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575928/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-office-interop-excel)
- [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527305/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-office-interop-excel-version-14-0-0)
- [Unit test with Microsoft.Office.Interop dll fails on build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762506/unit-test-with-microsoft-office-interop-dll-fails-on-build-server)